# How to run an Angular web app with a .net framework 4.7.1 WebAPI on the same port?

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2019

I have legacy dlls written in .net framework 4.7.1 and I have an Angular 7 web app that was written separately, using a REST API (currently with mock answers).
I want to create a WebAPI (preferably, also in .net 4.7.1) that runs on the same port as the web application, receives the REST requests, uses the 4.7.1 dlls to process the request and responds back.

I'm using visual studio 2019 and IIS Express to run the web app locally.

So far, I've created a new ASP.NET Framework WebAPI project and included the web apps folder content in the project folder.
I tried to follow this guide to make the web app run with the REST API:
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/27/build-crud-app-in-aspnet-framework-webapi-and-angular

I've added this to Web.config

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

and this to WebApiConfig.cs:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

as well as all the steps described in the article (except for the Authentication and DB modeling)

I've configured the projects URL to port 4200, but I'm getting "Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found." error when I go to http://localhost:8080/, although http://localhost:8080/api/[controller] REST works.

The result I'm looking for is to load the application on URL "localhost:XXXX" with the app.component as the default page and the REST to listen on "localhost:XXXX/api/[controller]" - at least until I'll change the URL for the WebAPI.
Note: The Angular app contains routing within itself too.

How can I manage to do that?

P.S. I managed to do this using ASP.NET Core 2.1 project but due to potential compatibility issues and to avoid Runtime exceptions, I need to run this in a .net 4.7.1 project.

Edit: the end goal is to run both the app and the WebAPI on the same service.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, each application normally runs in different ports

Comment: If one program is using a port, another program can't use that port, at least from my knowledge

Comment: My goal is to run all in one application (the web app) that can also listen to its own rest requests.